# I want to group by Solo column according to the same value and calculate its total by linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to group by Solo column according to the same value and calculate its total

[image: 1]

Comment: "Solo column"? What is Solo column? What have you tried so far? Show us your code

Comment: I want to group by its identical values and calculate the total amount after group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your object names are, so I'm going to give a generic sample that you should be able to translate for your domain.

```cs
var query = 
    from row in table
    group row by row.solo into grouped
    select new 
    { 
        Solo = grouped.Key,
        Total = grouped.Sum(g => g.ColumnToTotal)
    };
```